# Handle check box forms with an `:has_many :through` Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, field

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to use check box fields in my view files (that is, for new and edit forms) with an `:has_many :through` Record Association. I seen that kind of things *easily* implemented using an `has_and_belongs_to_many` Record Association, but is it possible to make that to work *easly* with the first mentioned association? If so, how to do that?

Comment: http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link Dogbert supplied is a good way of doing it manual. If you however decide to use [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) you get that functionality build in.

Using the example from the previously mentioned article you would do:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :groups, :as => :check_boxes %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This example is of course very simplified but it should work. Good luck!