# Rails 3 has_and_belongs_to_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I need help with implementing the nested form for a has_and_belongs_to_many

I have the following:

Models

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
end
```

Migrations

```
class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :code
      t.boolean :active
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :countries
  end
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.sting :name
      t.string :description
      t.boolean :active
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories
  end
end

class CreateCategoriesCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_countries, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :category
        t.references :country
    end
    add_index(:categories_countries, [:category_id, :country_id], :unique => true)
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories_countries
  end
end
```

View for Country where I want the nested categories in the form of checkboxes

```
<%= form_for @country do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :active %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :active %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to implement the  nested categories. Was seeking help in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for @country do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...
  <% Categories.all.each do |category| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label category.name %>
    // don't use f here
    <%= check_box :categories_ids,
                  category.id,
                  @country.categories.include?(category),
                  :name=>'country[categories_ids][]' %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

source: [Handle check box forms with an `:has_many :through` Record Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562364/handle-check-box-forms-with-an-has-many-through-record-association) => http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

Why do you use :allow_destroy => true ?

Comment: Yes you just want to set the associations, there is no need of field_for() for example.

Comment: for some reason the code ended up giving many errors. Finally I decided to not use the "accepts_nested_attributes_for" piece and take just the simple approach of just showing the check boxes.