# checkbox value with associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, associations

How can I save Employee's `Attendance` in `Attendance` table.
Association :

1. Employee has_many :Attendances.
2. Attendance belongs_to :Employee.

Here is the code:

```
<%= form_for @attendance do |f|  %>
<%= f.date_select :date %><br />
<button type="button" id="check_all">
    EmployeeName / Attendance
</button><br />
<table>
<%#=  hidden_field_tag "attendance[is_present]", '0'%>
<%  Employee.all.each do |emp|%>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <%= emp.first_name %><%= emp.last_name %></td>
    <td style="padding-left:50px;">
    <%#= check_box_tag 'attendance[is_present]', 1, (@data.attendance.is_present == 1 ? true : false)%>
    <%= f.check_box :is_present %></td>
    <td>
      <%= attendance.inspect %>
    <% @attendance.employee_id = emp.id  %>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
</script>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an Attendance `belongs_to` Employee, then the attendances table will have a single employee_id column and a given Attendance will only be able to link to one employee.  So I think you might want to change your model so that you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between Employee and Attendance.  Then you'll need an `attendances_employees` table to join them.

Once you have that connection between the models, check out [Handle check box forms with an `:has_many :through` Record Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562364/handle-check-box-forms-with-an-has-many-through-record-association).  There is a comment under the question that points to http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/ which has a really helpful example.  Just in case that site ever goes away, here is what you would want to set up in your view:

```
<%  Employee.all.each do |emp|%>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= label_tag "employee_id_#{emp.id}", "#{emp.first_name} #{emp.last_name}" %>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:50px;">
      <%= check_box_tag :employee_ids, emp.id, @attendance.employees.include?(emp), name: "attendance[employee_ids][]", id: "employee_id_#{emp.id}" %>
    </td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

You'll also need to have `attr_accessible :employee_ids` in your Attendance model.